# why signal emitting in QDialog can not invoke the connected slot in QThread?

Tags: python, pyside

This is my code:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import time

class TestThread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        self.finished_flag = False
        super(TestThread, self).__init__()

    def finished(self):
        print('==========finished function is invoked!=======================')
        self.finished_flag = True

    def run(self):
        while(True): 
            print('thread is running...') 
            time.sleep(1)            
            if self.finished_flag:
                print('thread exist!')
                break


class TestDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    ForceTermimateSignal = QtCore.Signal()

    def done(self, code):
        print('================dialog done!==================')
        self.ForceTermimateSignal.emit()
        super(TestDialog, self).done(code)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    dlg = TestDialog()
    testThread = TestThread()

    dlg.ForceTermimateSignal.connect(testThread.finished)

    testThread.start()

    dlg.exec_()

    if testThread.isFinished():
        print('thread finished')
    else:
        print('thread is still running!')
        testThread.wait()
```

This is the result when run the above code and then close the dialog:

```
thread is running...
thread is running...
thread is running...
thread is running...
================dialog done!==================
thread is still running!
thread is running...
thread is running...
thread is running...
```

so I want to know: why emitting ForceTermimateSignal of dlg can not invoke 'finished' function of object testThread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @ekhumoro, I referred to [Signals and Slots Across Threads](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html) of QT documentation and found that there were many different connection types in QT. Understanding these types, all is clear.

Replace the above code:

```
dlg.ForceTermimateSignal.connect(testThread.finished)
```

with:

```
dlg.ForceTermimateSignal.connect(teshThread.finished, type=Qt.DirectConnection)
```

then, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect a signal to a slot in the same thread, the slot will be invoked directly and synchronously. But when the connection is cross-thread, the signal will be posted as an event, and the slot will be invoked asynchronously.

So in your example, this line:

```
    self.ForceTermimateSignal.emit()
```

will add a signal-event to the dialog's event-queue and then return without directly invoking the thread's `finished` slot. The following line:

```
    super(TestDialog, self).done(code)
```

will then be executed immediately, which will terminate the event-loop before the signal-event has a chance to be processed.

If you replace the emit line with:

```
   testThread.finished_flag = True
```

the example should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you, I have tested your method, it works. But I still will try to find  a way to invoke a cross-thread slot synchronously by signal emitting, if I can't, I will accept this answer.